# String to NSdate returns nil

Tags: ios, swift, datetime, nsdateformatter

I want to separate my String dateTime to different variables date and time because I will display it separately. How could I do this?

Here's my code in getting the date only and it returns nil:

```
let datetime = "2015-04-06T13:24:11.913"
    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM-DD-YYYY"
    let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(datetime)
    println(date)
```

Thanks in advance.

Update:
This is my error,
[image]

Update 2:
It doesn't return an error but it gives me the wrong Month for the formatted date

[image]

Comment: Your date format doesn't come close to being the same format as the date string. They need to match.

Comment: What format will I use? And how can I separate the time and date to different variables? Thanks

Comment: Is your datestring local time or UTC ?

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus , I don't know. How can i know though?

Comment: it is probably UTC and if you don't specify it will treat as localtime

Comment: How can I change it then?

Comment: can you post the code instead of a screen shot so I can copy and edit it

Comment: let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"
        let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(datetime)
        let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        let components = calendar.components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitHour, fromDate: date!)
        println(components.month)

Comment: IDK, but I read about UTC and local time, the difference is only a matter of Hours, not Months.

Comment: I know what's the problem are you going to accept my answer ?

Comment: Alright but give the complete answer not only for my latest question because others might get confused. thanks

Comment: I have added the answer I will also add how to extract the components out of your date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the problem that the string you were testing had milliseconds while the date from your array has only seconds, now the problem is that Y is for week of year. You need to use lowercase "y" with the date format and also lowercase "d". The date format should look like this:

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
```

to extract the month component from a date you can use this extension:

```
extension Date {
    var month: Int {
        Calendar(identifier: .gregorian).component(.month, from: self)
    }
}


NSDate().month   // 5
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the difference between 'Y' and 'y'

Comment: @Apple this answer will help you extracting whatever you want from a date http://stackoverflow.com/a/27369380/2303865

Answer (score 5):

Use this formatter

```
let datetime = "2015-04-06T13:24:11.913"
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"
let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(datetime)
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let components = calendar.components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitHour, fromDate: date!)
components.day//This is 6
```

Your formatter have to match your string

This is my playground screenshot,it works well.
[image]

Comment: Okay, but how can I get separate variables for date and time?

Comment: See updates,you can get every part of a `NSDate` using `NSCalendar`

Comment: date variable is still nil though. It still returns an error

Comment: See my screenshot ,it works well.Please post your error

Comment: @Apple try deleting your Xcode caches, and derivedData and then restart your computer. I had a similar issue here and it solved it.

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus i already tried deleting my derived data. It still returns error. I updated my question, look at the error. thanks

Comment: I get my string datetime from an array, I tried hardcoding the date and it worked. I don't know what's wrong getting my string from the array because they have the same format. Any idea?

Comment: You need to delete the ".SSS" from your date format. "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"

Comment: your screen shot it is very clear datetime = "2015-04-06T12:46:05"

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus Alright. My bad also, turns out, your answers were right all along, i just gave wrong example on my datetime variable.

Answer (score 3):

```
        let datetime = "2015-04-06T13:24:11" //"2015-04-06T13:24:11.913"
        var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:mm:ss" //"yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"
        let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(datetime)
        let myTime = NSDateFormatter.localizedStringFromDate(date!, dateStyle: .NoStyle , timeStyle: .MediumStyle)
        let myDate = NSDateFormatter.localizedStringFromDate(date!, dateStyle: .ShortStyle , timeStyle: .NoStyle)

        println(date!)//DateWithTime
        println(myDate)//Date
        println(myTime)//time
```

This helps you for formatting.. [NSDateFormatter_Class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/)
[image] Thanks to @LeonardoSavioDabus for given this image => [Swift NSDate UTC time and local time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24917483/swift-nsdate-utc-time-and-local-tme)

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus thanks for this image it helps me lots.. :)

Comment: @Apple check your date formate and date string `2015-04-06T13:24:11` and you told us `2015-04-06T13:24:11.913`. I update my answer check this now

Comment: @Apple check your `datetime`? and remove `.SSS` from  `dateFormatter.dateFormat` it works.. Check and let me know.

Comment: @Yuyutsu yeah, my bad. Thanks though, your answer is convenient.

Comment: I was so focused on getting rid of the error, I didn't notice that it gives me the wrong month.

Answer (score 0):

All of the `NSDateFormatter`s in other answers will give the wrong date once the user sets the iOS calendar to anything other than the gregorian calendar. Your date string doesn't mention any timezone as well so I'm going to assume is UTC.

```
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")
formatter.calendar = NSCalendar.gregorianCalendar()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.SSS"
```

Comment: Actually the codes they gave works but apparently, it only works if the date is hardcoded. In my case, i get my string date time from an array, I don't know what seems to be the problem with that

Answer (score -1):

Try like this way,

```
    let datetime = "2015-04-06T13:24:11.913"
    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"
    let dateFromString = dateFormatter.dateFromString(datetime)
    var calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    var components:NSDateComponents = calendar.components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitSecond | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitHour, fromDate: dateFromString!)
    var stringDate = "\(components.month)-\(components.day)-\(components.year)"
    var stringTime = "\(components.hour):\(components.minute):\(components.second)"
    println(stringDate)
    println(stringTime)
```

You will get output Like :

> 4-6-2015
>
> 13:24:11

Enjoy Coding !!

Comment: Its running perfectly, can you post error in comment