# Date formatting error between different time zones

Tags: swift, date-formatting

I am trying to convert a string to an NSDate variable and print both the string and date. Because of an error in the date format, it always convert the hour of the string to hour+7 in date.

```
      let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
      dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZ"
      let date: NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(timeStamp)!

      println("String is is \(timeStamp)")
      println(date)
```

It prints `String is 2015-07-10T16:33:00-07:00` for the first line and `2015-07-10 23:33:00 +0000` for the second line.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Where are you in the world?

Comment: What's your issue? a NSDate and a NSString aren't the same. It's the same date, check the "-07:00".

Comment: Your date string is expressed with a time zone of -7 hours, so converted to a time zone of 0 (as the NSDateFormatter does) you are getting 7 added to 16:33, giving 23:33

Comment: oh i see now :) thanks @Clafou

Comment: @SılaGüler some good answers on setting the time zone http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24917483/swift-nsdate-utc-time-and-local-tme