# NSTimeZone initialisation results in "unable to read data"

Tags: ios, swift, foundation, nstimezone

I'm trying to initialise an NSTimeZone object like this:

```
var timezone = NSTimeZone.init(name: "Europe/Moscow")
```

instead of **nil** or a legit locale value - I get "unable to read data" in xCode's debugging tool

[image]

I got the timezone string ("Europe/Moscow") via `NSTimeZone.knownTimeZoneNames()`

I'm using **xCode 7**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: instead of var use let.Its working fine for me.

let  _timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "Europe/Moscow")
print(_timeZone)

Comment: Hm. Yeah the print statement gives me:
Optional(Europe/Moscow (GMT+3) offset 10800) - the debugger still shows "unable to read data"

Comment: The debugger variables view is sometimes just *wrong*. If print() gives the correct output then everything is OK.

Comment: @MartinR if you put that into an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments - the variables view was just ***wrong*** - a print() resulted in the correct output.

Running an iPhone 6 Simulator instead of an iPhone 5 simulator gives the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used that class before, but I'm guessing it should be `let timezone = NSTimeZone(name : "")`? Never seen a class initialized in that way.

Comment: Yes that's probably cleaner (y) - but it yields the same result

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine for me , use let instead of var.Check below
[image]

For reference 
[Swift NSDate UTC time and local time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24917483/swift-nsdate-utc-time-and-local-tme)

Comment: Hm - can you try running it with the IPhone 5 simulator? When running IPhone 6 simulator I get it correct aswell (regardless of using let or var)